# Python3: trying to compare values in csv with threshold

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open('C:/Users/adria/Desktop/breastCancerDataReducedDimensions.csv', mode = 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    for row in reader:
        next(reader)
        if row[2] >= 13:
            print(row[2])
```

I am trying to compare the values in this particular row to a threshold value, but i am getting an operand error saying that I cannot compare a string to an integer. I believe the header in the first row is causing my issue but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: try `int(row[2]) >= 13`, also why do you have `next(reader)` inside the loop? Are you trying to skip every other row?

Comment: Try `if int(row[2]) >= 13:`

Comment: No, I had moved the 'next(reader)' inside the loop to see if this would skip the header with no luck. I am still pretty new so I was moving some things around to see if that was my issue. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1):

`if int(row[2]) >= 13:` should do it, since the cell in the csv is prob interpreted as string